# How do I create an array in matlab consisting of multiple 3d imagedata arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I have 15 images that I am reading using `imagedata = imread('imagename.jpg')` its size is always `320 by 320 by 3`

How do I put the data in an array (using a for for loop) such that when I access the first element of the new array I get the RGB data of the first image I input?

Answer (score 3):

You should probably use `cell`

```
imCell = {};
for i = 1 :15
    imCell{i} = imread(num2str(something));
end
```

And you could easily have access,

```
for j = 1 : 15
    subplot(5,3,j);
    imshow(imCell{j});
end
```

`imCell` is a cell with size `1x15`. However `imCell{i}` is an arrey with size `320x320x3`.

Using cell will allow you to even save arrays of different sizes in it.

Comment: Nice. I think that should do the job. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since all images have the same size, it may be more efficient to use a 4D array than a cell array:

```
imArray = NaN(320,320,3,15);
for n = 1:15
    imArray(:,:,:,n) = imread(filename); %// filename should probably change
end
```

You can then access the first image as `imArray(:,:,:,1)`, etc.