# In Matlab, is there a way to quickly import a folder of images into a matrix?

Tags: image, matlab, import

Right now I'm using a for loop to import images into a matrix, where the columns are the RGB representation of said images. Here's my code:

```
for i=1:num_data_points
filename = sprintf('train/%d.png', i)
X(:,i)=reshape(imread(filename), [], 1);
end
```

My problem is that it's taking a really long time to import unless I'm using a small number of images (100-200), but since I'm using the CIFAR-10 dataset I would like to import the entire training set (10,000 images).

Is there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: Are you sure that you won't get `out of memory` if you import them all? what are the sizes? if they are `300x300`, then `10,000x300x300x3 = 2.7e9`.

Comment: They're 32x32. I'm not dead set on importing them all, but if there's a faster way to import 1000-2000 that would be great

Comment: I don't think you can avoid the loop, since `imgread` only accepts strings and passes them to `fopen`, which only works on single files. However, preallocation of `X` by `X = zeros(1024,num_data_points);` might improve performance a bit.

Comment: See here if using `cell` helps, maybe `reshape` takes much time, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26902877/how-do-i-create-an-array-in-matlab-consisting-of-multiple-3d-imagedata-arrays/26902919#26902919

Comment: @Nemesis that sped up my code quite a bit, thanks!